# Glue S3 Target Path matching two level specific sub folder

Tags: aws-glue

```
bucket/
├── seoul/
│   ├── weather/
│   │   └── data.json
│   └── gdp/
│       └── data.json
├── tokyo/
│   ├── weather/
│   │   └── data.json
│   ├── gdp/
│   │   └── data.json
│   └── transit/
│       └── data.json
├── seattle/
│   ├── weather/
│   │   └── data.json
│   └── cost-of-living/
│       └── data.json
├ ....
```

I wanted to crawl all `weather` data in my bucket. 
As described in [AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html), I set my S3 Target Path as

```
s3://bucket/*/weather
```

However the glue crawler doesn't match any datas. Creates 0 tables. How should I set glue targets so that I can gather all weather data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glob patterns are supported in exclusion pattern. So for your case try to set target as `s3://bucket/` and add exclusions for `*/gdp/**,*/transit/**,*/cost-of-living/**`

Comment: Yeah, but I worried if somebody writes data to `bucket/seoul/events`.

Answer (score 1):

If there's not much folders to exclude, @Yuriy Bondaruk has great answer. However, in my case, there are many folders to exclude and it doesn't guarantee that current file tree is fixed.

Therefore, I am going to build **nested** cloudFormation.

1. BASE Cloudformation: Take city as input and run crawler.
2. Very-Long Cloudformation template: give city name as parameter and call BASE cloudformation.